# How can I create time gaps in video recordings using newest version of FFMPEG?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I am new to the forum so I hope I've formulated this question correctly.

I have downloaded newest version of FFMPEG and I would like to use it to modify existing video by inserting time gaps in it.

Here is what I mean by time gap. If I have input video that lasts 2 seconds and was recorded at FPS=10, timestamps of its frames would be as follows:

```
0.1s, 0.2s,0.3s,0.4s, .. 1.7s, 1.8s, 1.9.s, 2s
```

If I would to introduce time gaps, input videos frame would be something like this:

```
0.1s, 0.2s, 0.9s, 1s, 1.1s, 1.7s, 1.8s, 1.9s, 2s
```

Is something like this possible to achieve?

!!!**EDIT**!!!

I would like to post here results of the commands Gyan was kind enough to comment.

For command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "setpts='PTS+gte(t,0.3)*(0.6/TB)+gte(t,1.5)*(1.1/TB)',showinfo" -vsync vfr out.mp4
```

I am getting:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:00:09.30, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1185 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 960x540, 1184 kb/s, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 10240 tbn, 20480 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
File 'out.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[Parsed_setpts_0 @ 0x55e4f4f85400] [Eval @ 0x7fffadb2ac80] Unknown function in 't,0.3)*(0.6/TB)+gte(t,1.5)*(1.1/TB)'
[Parsed_setpts_0 @ 0x55e4f4f85400] Error while parsing expression 'PTS+gte(t,0.3)*(0.6/TB)+gte(t,1.5)*(1.1/TB)'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x55e4f4eff400] Error initializing filter 'setpts' with args 'PTS+gte(t,0.3)*(0.6/TB)+gte(t,1.5)*(1.1/TB)'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

And for command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf select='not(between(t,0.3,0.7)+between(t,1.5.1.8))' -vsync vfr out.mp4
```

I am getting:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:00:09.30, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1185 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 960x540, 1184 kb/s, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 10240 tbn, 20480 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
File 'out.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[Parsed_select_0 @ 0x55ce2c4f9d00] [Eval @ 0x7ffc980730c0] Missing ')' or too many args in 'between(t'
[Parsed_select_0 @ 0x55ce2c4f9d00] Error while parsing expression 'not(between(t'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x55ce2c491a00] Error initializing filter 'select' with args 'not(between(t'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: Is audio present?

Comment: Thanks for fast reply! No it is not. @Gyan

Comment: Do you want to change timestamps of `0.3s,0.4s, .. ` or delete frames at those timestamps?

Comment: Would it be too much to ask for both? I initially wanted to change frame timestamps so I have some what time gaps between lets sat 5th frame and 6th frame. But it would be nice to know how I can delete frame at particular timestamps so I can deal with that issue as well. @Gyan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Shifting timestamps

This is possible using the setpts filter.

Assuming no audio, command would look like this

```
ffmpeg -i in -vf setpts='PTS+gte(T\,0.3)*(0.6/TB)+gte(T\,1.5)*(1.1/TB)' -vsync vfr out
```

This will offset all frames with timestamps 0.3s or greater forward by 0.6s. It will also offset all frames with timestamps 1.5s or greater forward by 1.1s. These latter set of frames will have both offsets applied to them, so net offset is 0.6 + 1.1 = 1.7s. Each offset group is composed of two parts: `(qualification)*(offset)`. All offset groups are added together with the original timestamp (`PTS`).

#### Removing frames

Assuming no audio, basic form is

```
ffmpeg -i in -vf select='not(between(t\,0.3\,0.7)+between(t\,1.5\,1.8))' -vsync vfr out
```

This will remove frames having timestamps between 0.3 and 0.7s and between 1.5s and 1.8s.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! For 1st command I am getting this error: `[Parsed_setpts_0 @ 0x556c7f860880] [Eval @ 0x7ffeccd99c00] Unknown function in 't,0.3)*(0.6/TB)+gte(t,1.5)*(1.1/TB)'
[Parsed_setpts_0 @ 0x556c7f860880] Error while parsing expression 'PTS+gte(t,0.3)*(0.6/TB)+gte(t,1.5)*(1.1/TB)'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x556c7f867400] Error initializing filter 'setpts' with args 'PTS+gte(t,0.3)*(0.6/TB)+gte(t,1.5)*(1.1/TB)'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!`

Comment: Corrected labels and escaped commas.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just have couple of more questions. When using command for DELETING FRAMES. I see that you have specified -vsync. I assume that is because you want to disable FFMPEGs duplicate/drop behavior. What is vfr for? Does it allow variable frame rate? Problem is that I am getting duplicate frames as a result.

What I mean is, my video has 100 frames (10 sec, 10FPS), and when I extract frames from out.mp4 that I got from your command I still get 100 frames. I expected to get 91 since it does not select  frames with [0.3,0.7] and [1.5, 1.8] timestamps. Instead I get duplicates

Comment: The image muxer defaults to vsync cfr, so you need to specify `-vsync vfr` or `-vsync 0` when extracting images.

Comment: I got both commands to work! Thank you very much for your help sir!