# Force FFMPEG to reuse gif frames

Tags: ffmpeg, gif

I am exporting a gif from a mov file using ffmpeg with the following code:

```
 ffmpeg -i movie.mov -i mypalette.png -lavfi "paletteuse,scale=600:-1" -r "25" -loop "0" movie.gif
```

The movie has a lot of pauses where the frame does not change. I noticed when opening the gif in Photoshop it is using duplicates of the same frame rather than pausing at that frame for say, 2 seconds.
Is there a method for forcing FFMEG to re-use identical frames?

Answer (score 4):

Use

`ffmpeg -i movie.mov -i mypalette.png -lavfi "mpdecimate,paletteuse,scale=600:-1" -vsync 0 -r 25 -loop 0 movie.gif`

The mpdecimate will remove duplicate frames from the input. The `-vsync 0` will prevent ffmpeg from populating the gaps created by mpdecimate with duplicate frames.

Comment: Thanks, this does create a smaller gif, but there is no delay on the final frame, like there is in the video. This is possible in photoshop

Comment: Add `-final_delay 5` to set delay for final frame to 500 mmilliseconds.

Comment: using `ffmpeg -i movie.mov -i mypalette.png -lavfi "mpdecimate,paletteuse,scale=600:-1" -vsync 0 -r 25 -loop 0 -final delay 5 movie.gif`gives me _Unrecognized option 'final'._

Comment: Sorry, there's an underscore between final and delay

Comment: Thanks `ffmpeg -i movie.mov -i mypalette.png -lavfi "mpdecimate,paletteuse,scale=600:-1" -vsync 0 -r 25 -loop 0 -final_delay 5 movie.gif` produces a gif, but does add any delay to the end. Also get lots of warnings like this _[gif @ 0x7f8a59819e00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 12, current: 12; changing to 13. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file._

Comment: and _Using -vsync 0 and -r can produce invalid output files_

Comment: What's the fps of the input?

Comment: the fps of the input is 30

Comment: Remove the `-r 25`.

Comment: Thanks, `ffmpeg -i movie.mov -i mypalette.png -lavfi "mpdecimate,paletteuse,scale=600:-1" -vsync 0 -loop 0 -final_delay 5 movie.gif` there are no errors, but still no delay/pause.

Comment: How are you checking for final delay?

Comment: Oops, final_delay is in centiseconds, so 5 leads to a final frame duration of 50 ms.

Comment: that works! One final question: an I add delays in specific places? Eg: at 2 seconds

Comment: You'll have to use the setpts filter. Basic template is as per the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56524334